# The CrystalReports cannnot be displayed

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports-xi

I'm new to CrystalReports and VB6, but I was asked to maintenance the system. We used VB6 and Crystal Reports XI R2, and the crystal rpeort is not displayed, it just flashed. The code is like this:

```
wk_where = ""
wk_where = wk_where & "{GNS_EXCEPTION_TRAN.TRANSACTION_CODE} = '" + CST_OCA_PLUS + "' "

wk_where = wk_where & "{GNS_EXCEPTION_TRAN.TRANSACTION_CODE} = '" + CST_OCA_PLUS + "' "
wk_where = wk_where & "AND YEAR({GNS_EXCEPTION_TRAN.CREATE_DATE}) = " +     Format(GetSYSDATE, "YYYY")
wk_where = wk_where & " AND MONTH({GNS_EXCEPTION_TRAN.CREATE_DATE}) = " +       Format(GetSYSDATE, "MM")
wk_where = wk_where & " AND DAY({GNS_EXCEPTION_TRAN.CREATE_DATE}) = " + Format(GetSYSDATE, "DD")

With Report_Stock_Increase
    .ReportFileName = REPORT_DIR + "Stock_Increase_Proof.rpt"
    'DB CONNECT
    .Connect = CONNECT_STR

    'WHERE SET
    .SelectionFormula = wk_where

    'PARAMETER
    wk_where = "Date : " + Format(GetSYSDATE, "MM/DD/YYYY")
    .Formulas(2) = "Print_Date = '" + wk_where + "'"


    .ReportTitle = "** STOCK INCREASE  PROOF LIST **"
    .WindowTitle = "STOCK INCREASE PROOF LIST"

    .WindowState = crptMaximized

    If REPORT_PVIEW = True Then
        .Destination = crptToWindow
    Else
        .Destination = crptToPrinter
    End If

    'Preview
    .PrintReport
```

Could someone help me?Thanks.

Comment: Is that all the code? For a start, there is no matching `End With`.

Comment: Do you have a Crystal directory under windows?  If you do have a look in there and see if there is a SQLSvr.err file, it might give you some extra error information.